# Inscribed Shapes of Equal Area

Tags: geometry, area

Does there exist a shape such that the largest inscribed circle and square of that shape have the same area? What would the shape look like? What about circle and semicircle? Triangle and circle? What if instead of area, perimeter? This can easily be generalized to any combination of polygons.

Comment: it's known that it's not possible to construct square equal to the area of a given circle and vice versa using usual geometry tools

Comment: @Vasya The question is about existence, though, not construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, certainly. Let $S$ be the square of width $2$ and $C$ the circle of radius $\frac2{\sqrt\pi}$ both centred at the origin. Both $S$ and $C$ have area $4$. Now consider $S \cup C$: clearly both $S$ and $C$ are the largest square and circle that fit inside.

You could consider adding restrictions to the problem: for example, does there exist a *convex* shape with the given property? It turns out that there does: see if you can modify $S \cup C$ to meet the new restriction.

Comment: Presumably the convex hull of $S \cup C$

Comment: @Henry Yes indeed.